# Ultegra on Trek Crockett 5

Tags: drivetrain

I have 2 questions regarding the switch to Ultegra. I already have Ultegra 32 cassette on my Trek because I build another set of Vision road wheels.

1. Would it be possible to switch completely from the SRAM Rival that I have at the moment to 2-11 Ultegra system ?
2. Would it be possible to just switch the rear derailleur and the shifters (already have Ultegra cassette) but leave the Rival crankset in order to have a 1-by-11 system?

Comment: What brakes do you have? Hydraulic SRAM and Shimano brakes are fundamentally incompatible. DOT brake fluid and mineral oil are used respectively.

Comment: I want to put a full ultegra system (brakes as well) , the idea behind the change come from the fact that i prefer Ultegra handles - and since i got the new wheels with ultegra cassette the shifting became way more smooth - thats why general i would like to switch (just debating myself if its possible to stay with ultegra 1-11)

Comment: Shimano offer now a rear mech with clutch, R8000. That should make Ultegra 1x11 easier for you.

Comment: but a full Ultegra system 2x11 can be placed on this frame , right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this: 'but a full Ultegra system 2x11 can be placed on this frame, right?'

Yes. Frames are not made specifically for either SRAM or Shimano groupsets.

As mentioned in comments you will have to swap out the shifters, rear derailleur and hydraulic brake calipers. Shimano rotors will be compatible I believe.

For the 1x option the SRAM crank can be left in place. The only difficulty I see is that I'm not sure if Shimano makes an Ultegra non-shifter front brake lever unit. You could use a regular shifter/brake unit of course.

For a 2x11 you will need a clamp on front derailleur, and a compatible crankset. It does not have to be a Shimano unit, you could use another vendors products such as FSA.

One thing to consider. Swapping out a whole groupset is expensive (taking into account cost of components and installation). You may find that selling the Crocket and buying a Ultegra equipped bike is the better option.